# Typescript creates error when map() an array in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have these components:

```
//parent
import React from 'react';
import SliderItem from "./SliderItem";

interface IProps {
    children: React.ReactNode,
}

const Slider: React.FC<IProps> & { SliderItem: React.FC<{title: string}> } = ({children}) => {
    console.log(children.map(i => i.props)); //TS2533: Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.
    return (
        <div>
            {children}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Slider;

Slider.SliderItem = SliderItem;

// children  component
import React from 'react';

const SliderItem: React.FC<{title: string}> = ({title}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {title}
        </div>
    );
};

export default SliderItem;
```

```
//render component
 <Slider>
    <Slider.SliderItem title="hi"/>
    <Slider.SliderItem title="hello"/>
 </Slider>
```

These components has the scope to create items for `Slider` component.
Trying to do `console.log(children.map(i => i.props)); //TS2533: Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.`, you can see the error. Why it appears and how to solve in my example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React children is possible null in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65898747/react-children-is-possible-null-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

This is because typescript is helping you out.
It is concerned that the 'i' might not have a property 'props' as it can be undefined.

You have two options.

1. Either do a check for the props property beforehand
2. Just add '? ' so that it proceeds only if the property is there.

```js
Children.map(i => console.log(i?.props) )
```

Comment: i added: `console.log(children ? children.map((i: any) => i.props) : 'no object');`, but now appears another issue: ` Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string | number | true | {} | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | ReactNodeArray | ReactPortal'.   Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'.`

Comment: Looks like children is not an array. Console out the children object and make sure it is an array

Comment: @KaranKumar note that's a *type* error, not a *runtime* error.